# Set k-largest elements of a tensor to zero in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to find **k** largest elements of each row of **h** and set zero value to those maximum elements.

I could be able to select the indexes of top most value of each row by using top_k function like:

```
top_k = tf.nn.top_k(h, 1)
```

But I could not use the indexes returned by top_k to update tensor.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, maybe there is a better solution. `tf.scatter_update()` doesn't work here because it can only modify parts of tensor along the **first dimension** (not an element in first row and second column for instance).

You have to get the `values` and `indices` from `tf.nn.top_k()` to create a sparse Tensor and subtract it to the initial Tensor `x`:

```py
x = tf.constant([[6., 2., 0.], [0., 4., 5.]])  # of type tf.float32

k = 2
values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(x, k, sorted=False)  # indices will be [[0, 1], [1, 2]], values will be [[6., 2.], [4., 5.]]

# We need to create full indices like [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1]]
my_range = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, indices.get_shape()[0]), 1)  # will be [[0], [1]]
my_range_repeated = tf.tile(my_range, [1, k])  # will be [[0, 0], [1, 1]]

# change shapes to [N, k, 1] and [N, k, 1], to concatenate into [N, k, 2]
full_indices = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(my_range_repeated, 2), tf.expand_dims(indices, 2)], axis=2)
full_indices = tf.reshape(full_indices, [-1, 2])

to_substract = tf.sparse_to_dense(full_indices, x.get_shape(), tf.reshape(values, [-1]), default_value=0.)

res = x - to_substract  # res should be all 0.
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't read well enough the question. I will update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Thank you Oliver, I got the idea. But when I tried it for k > 1, sparse_to_dense could not generate the tensor. I think, I need to play with tensorflow to be able to understand it. Numpy/tensorflow coding style gets difficult for me, because I have a Java mindset :-)

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thanks it worked. I had to set validate_indices to false to disable checking indice orders.

Comment: For unknown sizes, I had to change `indices.get_shape()[0]` to `tf.shape(indices)[0]`.

Comment: Syntax of [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) has changed. So in the code from the answer arguments should be flipped, or passed by name: `full_indices = tf.concat(axis=2, values=[tf.expand_dims(my_range_repeated, 2), tf.expand_dims(indices, 2)])`

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the opposite problem and wanted a operation which supported gradients. `top_k` does not support gradient propagation and hence a good way will be to implement the function in c++.

`top_k` c++ code is found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/core/kernels/topk_op.cc).

Your operation's kernel will look look like this:

```
template <typename T>
class MakeSparseOp : public OpKernel {
   public:
    explicit MakeSparseOp(OpKernelConstruction *context) : OpKernel(context) {}

    void Compute(OpKernelContext *context) override {
        // Grab the input tensors
        const auto &k_in = context->input(1);

        OP_REQUIRES(context, TensorShapeUtils::IsScalar(k_in.shape()),
                    errors::InvalidArgument("k must be scalar, got shape ",
                                            k_in.shape().DebugString()));

        int k = k_in.scalar<int32>()();
        OP_REQUIRES(context, k >= 0,
                    errors::InvalidArgument("Need k >= 0, got ", k));

        const Tensor &x_in = context->input(0);
        OP_REQUIRES(context, x_in.dims() >= 1,
                    errors::InvalidArgument("input must be >= 1-D, got shape ",
                                            x_in.shape().DebugString()));
        OP_REQUIRES(
            context, x_in.dim_size(x_in.dims() - 1) >= k,
            errors::InvalidArgument("input must have at least k columns"));



        // Flattening the input tensor
        const auto &x = x_in.flat_inner_dims<T>();

        const auto num_rows = x.dimension(0);
        const auto num_cols = x.dimension(1);

        TensorShape output_shape = x_in.shape();

        // Create an output tensor
        Tensor *x_out = nullptr;
        OP_REQUIRES_OK(context,
                       context->allocate_output(0, output_shape, &x_out));

        /*
         * Get the top k values along the first dimension for input
         */

        auto x_sparse = x_out->flat_inner_dims<T>();

        if (k == 0) return;  // Nothing to do

        // Using TopN to get the k max element
        gtl::TopN<std::pair<T, int32>> filter(k);

        x_sparse = x; // Copy all elements

        for (int r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {
            // Processing a row at a time
            for (int32 c = 0; c < num_cols; c++) {
                // The second element is the negated index, so that lower-index
                // elements
                // are considered larger than higher-index elements in case of
                // ties.
                filter.push(std::make_pair(x(r, c), -c));

            }

            for (auto top_k_it = filter.unsorted_begin();
                 top_k_it != filter.unsorted_end(); ++top_k_it) {
                x_sparse(r, -top_k_it->second) = 0; // Set max k to zero
            }

            filter.Reset();
        }
    }
};
```

My implementation for a related problem is [here](https://github.com/ayushbaid/MakeSparseTF).

Answer (score 1):

With recent availability of `scatter_nd_update` function in tensorflow, here is a modified version of the answer from [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5098368/olivier-moindrot).

```py
k = 2
val_to_replace_with = -333
x = tf.Variable([[6., 2., 0.], [0., 4., 5.]])  # of type tf.float32


values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(x, k, sorted=False)  # indices will be [[0, 1], [1, 2]], values will be [[6., 2.], [4., 5.]]
# We need to create full indices like [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1]]
my_range = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, tf.shape(indices)[0]), 1)  # will be [[0], [1]]
my_range_repeated = tf.tile(my_range, [1, k])  # will be [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
# change shapes to [N, k, 1] and [N, k, 1], to concatenate into [N, k, 2]
full_indices = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(my_range_repeated, -1), tf.expand_dims(indices, -1)], axis=2)
full_indices = tf.reshape(full_indices, [-1, 2])


# only significant modification -----------------------------------------------------------------
updates = val_to_replace_with + tf.zeros([tf.size(indices)], dtype=tf.float32)
c = tf.scatter_nd_update(x, full_indices, updates)
# only significant modification -----------------------------------------------------------------


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the Olivier Moindrot's idea, but implemented by tf's API.

```py
x = tf.constant([[6., 2., 0.], [0., 4., 5.]])  # of type tf.float32
k = 2
values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(x, k, sorted=False)  # indices will be [[0, 1], [1, 2]], values will be [[6., 2.], [4., 5.]]


# We need to create full indices like [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1]]
ii, _ = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(2), tf.range(k), indexing='ij')
full_indices = tf.reshape(tf.stack([ii, indices], axis=-1), [-1, len(x.shape)])


tf.tensor_scatter_nd_sub(x, full_indices, tf.reshape(values, -1))
"""
In [249]: tf.tensor_scatter_nd_sub(x, full_indices, tf.reshape(values, -1))
Out[249]: 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
"""
```